# Can I see a list of tags I am subscribed to?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, subscription

I looked through meta, and it doesn't look like anyone's asked this before.

At https://stackoverflow.com/tags, I can view tags organized by the *popular*, *name*, or *new* tabs. Is there somewhere else on SO that I can view a list of tags I am currently subscribed to?

If not, should a *subscriptions* tab be added as another tab on the tags page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is available at your stackexchange.com network profile

Click on your user page where it says "network profile". Once that loads click on the subscriptions tab.

Answer (score 2):

There's a link on your [preferences page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155351/rob?tab=prefs) to ["tag subscriptions"](https://stackexchange.com/filters), but it doesn't seem to work right; it just loads the last filter I looked at on stackexchange.com. It might work for you, I'm not sure exactly what's wrong with it

Comment: Hmm, appears to be broken on my end as well. Thanks for the heads up, though.